# how to fetch data from form's input and pass it into same form's action laravel

Tags: laravel, get

So my code looks like this:

```
<form method="get" action="{{URL::to('users', $_GET['username'])}}">
     <input type="text" name="username">
     <input class="but-submit"  type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I want my link to look like users/anydata, so that I could use it to fetch info from database.

My controller look like this:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Comment: Using JavaScript, you could prevent the form from submitting, compose the URL and then redirect to that URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you.

--**Write a JavaScript function and update the URL**

```html
<form name="mForm" method="get" onSubmit="formSubmitAction(this)">

function formSubmitAction()
{
 var username = document.getElementsByName("username").value;
 document.mForm.action = "http://yourURL.com/"+username; 
 document.myForm.submit();
}
```